# Dealing with the scope of variables: inside loop

Tags: go

As a JS dev jumping right into Go, I've hit a deadend trying to print multiple descriptions if the length of `commits` is more than one. I don't have much time left to complete this and I've been searching for longer than I wish. Any idea on how I could either restructure this or get this to work?

```golang
        case github.PushPayload:
            push := payload.(github.PushPayload)
            repo := push.Repository.Name
            owner := push.Repository.Owner.Login
            ownerUrl := push.Repository.Owner.HTMLURL
            ownerAvatar := push.Repository.Owner.AvatarURL
            ref := push.Ref
            refTrim := strings.Replace(ref, "/.*/", "", -1)
            commits := push.Commits


            for _, commit := range commits {
                message := commit.Message
                url := commit.URL
                id := commit.ID
                idShort := id[0:6]
                committer := commit.Committer.Username
                description := "[`" + idShort + "`](" + url + ") " + message + " - " + committer
            }


            if len(commits) == 1 {
                discord.ChannelMessageSendEmbed(channelID, &discordgo.MessageEmbed{
                    Color:       0x00B1FF,
                    Description: description,
                    Title:       "[" + repo + ":" + refTrim + "] 1 new commit! ",
                    Author: &discordgo.MessageEmbedAuthor{
                        Name:    owner,
                        URL:     ownerUrl,
                        IconURL: ownerAvatar,
                    },
                })
            } else {
                discord.ChannelMessageSendEmbed(channelID, &discordgo.MessageEmbed{
                    Color:       0x00B1FF,
                    Description: description,
                    Title:       "[" + repo + ":" + refTrim + "] " + string(len(commits)) + " new commits! ⚒️",
                    Author: &discordgo.MessageEmbedAuthor{
                        Name:    owner,
                        URL:     ownerUrl,
                        IconURL: ownerAvatar,
                    },
                })
            }
```

PS: Ignore `string(len(commits))` I know that's incorrect, I'm stuck trying to figure this out first and foremost. Also ignore: `refTrim := strings.Replace(ref, "/.*/", "", -1)`, which isn't correct either.

Comment: @mkopriva I'm not sure what the means exactly, sorry. I'm trying my best to understand nonetheless

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#:~:text=String%20concatenation ?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations piling up spec ref in case it is any use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to declare description variable before the loop and then add commit descriptions to it as below inside the loop.

Note: I emitted other code blocks here.

```
    description := ""
    for _, commit := range commits {
        description = description + "commit description here"
    }
```

`description += "commit description here"`  also can be used inside the loop. But I have added above to more understanding.

Comment: further more, in OP code description variable is not available outside the loop because its scope does not goes beyond the outer most closest bracket.